# replace value in a json within a makefile using sed

Tags: sed, makefile

I have a json file

```
{
  "mode": "~test",
  "data": "download",
  "result": "aaa",
  "api_version", "12"
}
```

and I have a makefile

```
test:
        GIT_REV=$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
        sed -e 's/"api_version": [^\]*/"api_version": "$$(GIT_REV)"/' test.json
```

which finds the pattern but can not replace the value.

I also tried

```
sed -e 's/"api_version": [^\]*/"api_version": "$(GIT_REV)"/' test.json
```

but gives the error : `make: GIT_REV: No such file or directory`

however, outside the makefile I can run

```
sed -e 's/"api_version": [^\]*"/"api_version": "'$GIT_REV'"/g' test.json
```

I wonder how I can modify the sed command inside the makefile to replace the json value. My goal is to replace the value within the json through the make file. The value is the git commit id.

Answer (score 0):

The setting of `GIT_REV` here is part of a recipe which means it's setting *shell* variable.  Each line of a recipe in a makefile is run in a different shell, so setting a shell variable on a line by itself is useless.

Then in the next line, you use `$$(GIT_REV)` which is not a make variable reference (because you use `$$` to escape it from make).

You don't give us much information about what you REALLY want to do, but given this makefile this will work:

```
GIT_REV = 3434

test:
        sed -e 's/"api_version": [^\]*/"api_version": "$(GIT_REV)"/' test.json
```

Comment: it gives me the error -> make: GIT_REV: No such file or directory. Let me update the question - I updated the question. hope it clarifies the goal.

Comment: If you got that error then you did something different than what I wrote above.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you cannot put the assignment of `GIT_REV` into a recipe like that.  That's (a) setting a shell variable, not a make variable, and (b) every command that make invokes is run in a separate shell.  You need to either use shell variables throughout, or use make variables throughout.  You can't mix and match them.

Comment: worked :-) so basically, I made them into one line -> sed -ie 's/"api_version": [^\]*/"api_version": "$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)"/' test.json

Comment: Why use `$(shell ...)`?  That just (IMO) adds confusion.  You're already _IN_ a shell script, that's what a makefile recipe is, so just using the shell you're already in rather than a make `$(shell ...)` function is simpler to understand.  YMMV: `$$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`